# iOS App crashes after splash screen. any help reading crash logs?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, crash

I have an app that runs fine attached to Xcode 11.5, but when disconnected from Xcode and standalone on iPhone, it crashes after displaying the splash screen with the below logs.

Curiously it works perfectly on Xcode 12.0 beta three, both connected and unconnected from Xcode. The crash log file seems to just indicate that it crashed with code 0x0000000000000000, to me the remaining part of the log is just gibberish.  (partial log because of size limits here)

Does anything jump out at you?

```
Incident Identifier: D547AD8C-3B86-47A8-99DE-834E3E81DF30
CrashReporter Key:   ba2b613dd2927a829e7827e06b8f0d0b80d02667
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,3
Process:             altitude.speed.location [4751]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1528656A-9C54-4553-90E0-6B923C5837A0/altitude.speed.location.app/altitude.speed.location
Identifier:          jwestveer.altitude-speed-location
Version:             1.4.2.1 (1.4.2.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           jwestveer.altitude-speed-location [919]


Date/Time:           2020-07-24 09:08:05.1238 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-07-24 09:08:05.0150 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.60.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a7dc1794 __exceptionPreprocess + 224
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a7ae3bcc objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a7cb7b98 +[NSException raise:format:] + 107
3   UIFoundation                    0x1ab3c5d54 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 403
4   UIFoundation                    0x1ab362cac -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 307
5   UIKitCore                       0x1abafdbbc -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 127
6   UIKitCore                       0x1abafe2cc -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection initWithCoder:] + 67
7   UIFoundation                    0x1ab3c5e94 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 723
8   UIFoundation                    0x1ab3c60b4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1267
9   UIFoundation                    0x1ab362cac -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 307
10  UIKitCore                       0x1abaf8cd8 -[NSCoder+ 7072984 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 487
11  UIKitCore                       0x1abafb858 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1063
12  UIKitCore                       0x1ab8241b4 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 363
13  UIKitCore                       0x1ab824c2c -[UIViewController loadView] + 175
14  UIKitCore                       0x1ab824ee4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 171
15  UIKitCore                       0x1ab8255e8 -[UIViewController view] + 27
16  UIKitCore                       0x1abe9fc50 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 175
17  UIKitCore                       0x1abe9f38c -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 227
18  UIKitCore                       0x1abea02ec -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 351
19  UIKitCore                       0x1abeb1170 -[UIWindow _mainQueue_makeKeyAndVisible] + 47
20  UIKitCore                       0x1abe602b0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3175
21  UIKitCore                       0x1abe6629c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1243
22  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60ab70 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 147
23  UIKitCore                       0x1ababb2dc _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 99
24  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60b654 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 195
25  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60b0a8 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 287
26  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60b480 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 739
27  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60ad40 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 335
28  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60f1dc __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 187
29  UIKitCore                       0x1ab9df3a0 +[BSAnimationSettings+ 5919648 (UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 811
30  UIKitCore                       0x1abad4720 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 243
31  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60ef38 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 139
32  UIKitCore                       0x1abad461c _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 99
33  UIKitCore                       0x1ab60eda0 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 375
34  UIKitCore                       0x1ab47ef74 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 635
35  UIKitCore                       0x1ab47db14 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 247
36  UIKitCore                       0x1ab47ecac -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 219
37  UIKitCore                       0x1abe644e8 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 539
38  UIKitCore                       0x1aba0468c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 359
39  FrontBoardServices              0x1acf3861c -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 423
40  FrontBoardServices              0x1acf5d194 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 99
41  FrontBoardServices              0x1acf42bfc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 231
42  FrontBoardServices              0x1acf5ce50 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 311
43  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a7a87524 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
44  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a7a61808 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 215
45  FrontBoardServices              0x1acf81850 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 39
46  FrontBoardServices              0x1acf8151c -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 403
47  FrontBoardServices              0x1acf81a44 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 27
48  CoreFoundation                  0x1a7d3fc18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 23
49  CoreFoundation                  0x1a7d3fb70 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 79
50  CoreFoundation                  0x1a7d3f2f8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 183
51  CoreFoundation                  0x1a7d3a328 __CFRunLoopRun + 787
52  CoreFoundation                  0x1a7d39ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 423
53  GraphicsServices                0x1b1e8438c GSEventRunModal + 159
54  UIKitCore                       0x1abe68444 UIApplicationMain + 1931
55  altitude.speed.location         0x10497051c 0x104950000 + 132380
56  libdyld.dylib                   0x1a7bc18f0 start + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a7bb6d88 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7ad374c pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a7a22934 abort + 100
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7b8acc0 __cxxabiv1::__aligned_malloc_with_fallback+ 76992 (unsigned long) + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7b7ce10 demangling_unexpected_handler+ 19984 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a7ae3e80 _objc_terminate+ 24192 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7b8a14c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 74060 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a7b8a0e4 std::terminate+ 73956 () + 44
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a7a87538 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a7a61808 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001acf81850 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001acf8151c -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 404
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001acf81a44 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d3fc18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d3fb70 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d3f2f8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 184
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d3a328 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d39ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b1e8438c GSEventRunModal + 160
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001abe68444 UIApplicationMain + 1932
20  altitude.speed.location         0x000000010497051c 0x104950000 + 132380
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a7bc18f0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a7b95198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a7b9460c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d3f468 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d3a49c __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a7d39ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a807d01c -[NSRunLoop+ 32796 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a807cefc -[NSRunLoop+ 32508 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001abf0b5dc -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a81abe20 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7ad7d98 _pthread_start + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb74c thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a7adb738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001a7b8df29   x5: 0x000000016b4ae480   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000500
    x8: 0x0000000104d31840   x9: 0x9c180b80e7b3ce97  x10: 0x00000001a7acf160  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001e2f63080  x13: 0x0000000000000021  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000001  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x0000000104d31920  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000104d31920
   x24: 0x0000000000001d03  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x00000002800cc508  x27: 0x000000016b4aec60
   x28: 0x00000001f1d6c000   fp: 0x000000016b4ae3e0   lr: 0x00000001a7ad374c
    sp: 0x000000016b4ae3c0   pc: 0x00000001a7bb6d88 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x104950000 - 0x10497ffff altitude.speed.location arm64  <3cc6c41f97ca3c79a95fcda4097c5eaa> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1528656A-9C54-4553-90E0-6B923C5837A0/altitude.speed.location.app/altitude.speed.location
0x104a90000 - 0x104a9bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64  <927690b4ce6e3dbb8d54d00bd46e211c> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x104cc4000 - 0x104d27fff dyld arm64  <c9d0dd090ebd3364b6b6d3baeb788dbf> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1a7966000 - 0x1a797cfff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <c70a923b37ad3f8a8e0873a3157620b1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1a797d000 - 0x1a79aefff libxpc.dylib arm64  <d54676d1b91b309b8f35ed171eff1612> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1a79af000 - 0x1a79affff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <5ecacf25aea7392db0edea47df03841f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1a79b0000 - 0x1a7a2bfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <7de48f8fc80f3f6582e5438a038914de> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1a7a2c000 - 0x1a7aa0fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <652a10daa0e73b479c95af3dfe45a66c> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1a7aa1000 - 0x1a7ac1fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <9dfc8592541931188bfd2e39417bb3ea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1a7ac2000 - 0x1a7accfff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <3834105b0f623e9ba9f7b9f29a2b7e1b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1a7acd000 - 0x1a7addfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <4f339f5eab9c39239a054f32d6361a9f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1a7ade000 - 0x1a7b0ffff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <8e7331ccb39b39c3bce21c8fc3fd640c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1a7b10000 - 0x1a7b77fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <eeebbbdc9c863e0c8d1650c6376c69c4> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1a7b78000 - 0x1a7b90fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <23af4b8a9578339983a8ba171a4a6984> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1a7b91000 - 0x1a7bbffff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <3b6ed4dcb4a437a581867d8d2cc888eb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1a7bc0000 - 0x1a7bf2fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <3d6d64b4cb2b3cc4a7e902774df7ae74> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1a7bf3000 - 0x1a7bfbfff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <fa0df7426de6311e93d6607ff8317f8e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x1a7bfc000 - 0x1a7c55fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <c5a6adff5bc33037ae3ee8107e311554> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1a7c56000 - 0x1a7c96fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <1ba5618b578f3c16b9fd96243b982e37> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1a7c97000 - 0x1a800afff CoreFoundation arm64  <50cf3336313f3a7d9048cb1ed8ec3368> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1a800b000 - 0x1a8074fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <97d4a21f62de39d4bac3eda6e23b867b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1a8075000 - 0x1a832cfff Foundation arm64  <c82f8a4f3d0f33db8d40c1e8bef27e56> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1a832d000 - 0x1a835ffff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <7866c08c0a1f38fbaa972690df5d31a3> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1a8360000 - 0x1a84dafff CoreServices arm64  <fb61d083d56b361ca997727e291dffe9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x1a84db000 - 0x1a853bfff libSparse.dylib arm64  <a2c74bcc9f6d34ed9720e4a265e297ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x1a853c000 - 0x1a8a26fff ImageIO arm64  <43e9306e349b3872a9b8b3239218efe1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1a8a27000 - 0x1a8a29fff ConstantClasses arm64  <bd7142b42f5139e894c2d0b7f671dc2b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x1a8a2a000 - 0x1a8bc8fff CoreText arm64  <155a11781fb53b7da110e84a79ce3207> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x1a8bc9000 - 0x1a8cfefff Security arm64  <a9bfe02f306b3ee7a40322cfb1bb9aaa> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1a8cff000 - 0x1a8da2fff IOKit arm64  <412da55765be384aa89d20a2b651c60e> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1a8da3000 - 0x1a8ddafff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <31b92bfd73383ece975dfd316e355aa1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1a8ddb000 - 0x1a8e37fff libprotobuf.dylib arm64  <841ca362c6873dfd84528cac6a2cd9c0> /usr/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
0x1a8e38000 - 0x1a8e49fff libprotobuf-lite.dylib arm64  <7536ad4fbc5c3354af80689a2324924a> /usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.dylib
0x1a8e4a000 - 0x1a909afff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <07864dddec643dd4b9a213200969c011> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1a90c5000 - 0x1a910cfff WirelessDiagnostics arm64  <5843debc06fd3e178fa388ba71a877b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
0x1a910d000 - 0x1a9146fff libAWDSupport.dylib arm64  <cb3af95f0538380891eccbd61ec40192> /usr/lib/libAWDSupport.dylib
0x1a9147000 - 0x1a95cafff CoreAudio arm64  <123334ddbe8b393c8ded639235cc34c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1a95cb000 - 0x1a9897fff CoreImage arm64  <de9d96b2048c3f09b4d1314870f137b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x1a99ce000 - 0x1a9b50fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <50368f42182239ecbb7d9e28f2cb51d4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1a9b51000 - 0x1a9b83fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <9a1e1f562fe5348c986dc3021bac41bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1a9b84000 - 0x1a9b8dfff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <da91f7854f5d3228bd9e869447a7c34d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1a9fb7000 - 0x1a9ff4fff AppSupport arm64  <d31707fec6183ce59ff3b8002015da90> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x1a9ff5000 - 0x1aa4c7fff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <53347c285841393f8a4ddb34799c75b1> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x1aa4c8000 - 0x1aa5d4fff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <de81fe303b2f367cb5b62a8a898433b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x1aa5d5000 - 0x1aa5fefff CoreServicesStore arm64  <2bf3563076013293a6053c4c54d896e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/CoreServicesStore
0x1aa5ff000 - 0x1aa61ffff UserManagement arm64  <07e5026006443636bcdae4734557d986> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
0x1aa8d8000 - 0x1aa8eefff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <2da9d6e47a603a5bb7f9580b31477a14> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1aa8ef000 - 0x1aa909fff CommonUtilities arm64  <d30d4f0820ea3f1ba814e827ba0af31b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1aa90a000 - 0x1aa90afff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <ffa48c1c677231e187723e30deeffeb5> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1aa90b000 - 0x1aa941fff RunningBoardServices arm64  <a20c63500ef83edbb889f5ddbda003bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RunningBoardServices.framework/RunningBoardServices
0x1aa942000 - 0x1aa9befff BaseBoard arm64  <85a351e7c0c131bca0ade2cb67207653> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x1aaf14000 - 0x1aaf86fff CoreLocation arm64  <9836af7d3a913fadb09cb6994baf3890> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x1aaf94000 - 0x1aafe7fff Accounts arm64  <2bf74d45d81638dcbfbfbdebd52a8dc9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1aaff9000 - 0x1ab35afff CFNetwork arm64  <65f4b06044a6399dae37054295956158> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1ab35b000 - 0x1ab439fff UIFoundation arm64  <7c505b75a2a9369e96a883adb4376aa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x1ab43a000 - 0x1ac554fff UIKitCore arm64  <bd57bd6e12b43f9285ca754932da499d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1ac555000 - 0x1ac562fff AssertionServices arm64  <79768aa2a40a3cbaa30f184b510d2d5e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1ac563000 - 0x1ac635fff CoreTelephony arm64  <b90e9fb79d943bd89f9132ff8771be92> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1ac636000 - 0x1ac63bfff AggregateDictionary arm64  <3dbe2791e6e43acc979739a8cdbeced9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x1ac63c000 - 0x1ac652fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <4c9b25c01cd03eed8add79a5b57f927b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1ac6cc000 - 0x1ac9f4fff CoreData arm64  <71c2361d6162376dbcc125d7dd75669a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1acc5e000 - 0x1acc88fff BoardServices arm64  <3e864ffd7b073032b8a42e9ce57a880b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BoardServices.framework/BoardServices
0x1acd3e000 - 0x1acd4cfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <eb9e62efbb8b300ab9c139f25856319b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1acd4d000 - 0x1acd6dfff CoreAnalytics arm64  <94498ba0e7fa338ba1289d84968ce676> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/CoreAnalytics
0x1acede000 - 0x1acf2bfff SpringBoardServices arm64  <4f1dc2cb19f63076a88ed6191effcade> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x1acf2c000 - 0x1acf9efff FrontBoardServices arm64  <6a942cc34b733477af9f95c8edcb8c85> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1acf9f000 - 0x1ad0c6fff Network arm64  <e3c994c5c94934a0b9c8a9162660b505> /System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Network
0x1ad124000 - 0x1ad12bfff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <22082eb064283a988e827b97d1f153d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1ad12c000 - 0x1ae015fff GeoServices arm64  <15129e9f5f7f3c77bb2908308c78afbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x1ae016000 - 0x1ae01efff TCC arm64  <bb908ebc51da300c8b85cb0af71a9706> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x1ae01f000 - 0x1ae078fff IMFoundation arm64  <ab9a5e9bb7ff308090687bf92773342e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x1ae079000 - 0x1ae1ecfff CoreUtils arm64  <c3cd19972ec132dc87242402385e853f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x1ae2d5000 - 0x1ae2defff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <f221bea37b46392cb7dd0a0fe7c07c44> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x1ae2df000 - 0x1ae35afff AppleAccount arm64  <4c2cc696222f3179b510d28bd91c4b6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x1ae35b000 - 0x1ae376fff ApplePushService arm64  <c7cf2c1aef533911b363c68710e50967> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x1ae377000 - 0x1ae45ffff IDS arm64  <300bd79bac543a76be770441b1bb37c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x1ae460000 - 0x1ae58afff IDSFoundation arm64  <c45d2047bcff31ef9902726f87422ae4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x1ae58b000 - 0x1ae58cfff libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib arm64  <fc9059f17df03681b82a1e1eccc9ffdc> /usr/lib/libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib
0x1ae5f1000 - 0x1ae6f1fff CoreMedia arm64  <d9f289d8e83b380396157009e1094713> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1ae6f2000 - 0x1ae701fff UIKitServices arm64  <3eee112dd96c3980a68969cd09a3d04f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitServices.framework/UIKitServices
0x1ae702000 - 0x1ae75dfff BackBoardServices arm64  <7e4bbf2499a23fb5a3c4e380f27b7b25> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x1ae75e000 - 0x1ae9affff QuartzCore arm64  <cf72678241d539a68a87ae03f4f07584> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1ae9b0000 - 0x1aea77fff ColorSync arm64  <95d2b119e3b136d88755c2d0ee68e7e4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x1aea78000 - 0x1aefe7fff CoreGraphics arm64  <0de7c48a285e336aa0892fd49635300c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1af119000 - 0x1af147fff UserNotifications arm64  <8025920b36003c45ae04901f5b9f96ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
0x1af148000 - 0x1af16bfff LocationSupport arm64  <022fc28a220938bb98895dac79b77fe6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LocationSupport.framework/LocationSupport
0x1af90b000 - 0x1b16c0fff WebCore arm64  <665cd83b3f283d9eb3b1e51e53285f9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x1b16c1000 - 0x1b16dbfff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <4caf798e480e338facab4d80ec282cef> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x1b16dc000 - 0x1b16e7fff AXCoreUtilities arm64  <7f78c74b27a0325aac828ff60350aaab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AXCoreUtilities.framework/AXCoreUtilities
0x1b175c000 - 0x1b1770fff PowerLog arm64  <d81cc5a8419b313bba353d2a2aad8e6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1b1771000 - 0x1b1782fff IOSurface arm64  <0ea65ad7b698333baabfced9d05e17b5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x1b1783000 - 0x1b1e80fff MediaToolbox arm64  <f53fce8dfa723ff98e32d52f40f80c93> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x1b1e81000 - 0x1b1e89fff GraphicsServices arm64  <0f9f2b391e8536349022ee6c8b55ca27> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1b1f72000 - 0x1b216afff AVFoundation arm64  <d4cd8c0f3b463bbcbd78e70f427068cf>
```

EOF

Comment: Are you using MapKit? WebKit?

Comment: MapKit.  No compile errors, No errors when running with Xcode attached. Crash when running without Xcode attached or running.

Comment: Ok. So. Have you checked the answer?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123412 :  Learn something every day.

Comment: jwestveer.altitude-speed-location-default)) will be created as active

Comment: jwestveer.altitude-speed-location with pid '5356' is now Terminated. Background entitlement: NO ActiveLongFormVideoSession: NO WhitelistedLongFormVideoApp NO

Comment: so nothing indicative of why the process was terminated.  I am sure that it might be something in the nib, but as I have used a storyboard I have not modified the nib or written any nib directly.  Probably something in Xcode, as the beta version allows the program to run correctly.

Comment: Ok. So. Have you checked the answer? Have you been on a second link as well? Have you checked that MapKit is LINKED to project correctly? You gave clear answer about nothing.

Comment: I am not familiar with how or why I would add mapkit to the frameworks.  Perhaps I am a bit thick.

Comment: So select the target you want to link with. Then go to the General tab and click (+) in Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content section, then select your framework and click Add. Link the framework to the app.

Comment: the second link in my answer contains illustration.